# Representation of the dual of $C_b(X)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

On a metric space $X$, [Did said](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73937/1281):

> the space $M_1$ of probability measures is included in the dual of the space $C_b$ of bounded continuous functions.

I was wondering what is the representation theorem for the dual of $C_b(X)$, which is supposed to have $M_1$ as its subset?

I saw in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), only Riesz representation theorems for $C_0$ and $C_c$, not for $C_b$.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: No representation theorem needed. Just integrate with respect to $\mu \in M_1$ to get a continuous linear functional on $C_b(X)$.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks! (1) In that scenario, is $C_b(X)$ endowed with the the supremum norm? (2) Can the continuous dual of $C_b(X)$ be represented as a set of measures which contains $M_1$?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) No.

Comment: @Martin: Why no for (2)? The continuous dual of $C_b(X)$ cannot be represented somehow?

Comment: You edited your question (2)... For the new (2): $C_b(X) = C(\beta X)$ and apply the Riesz representation theorem for $\beta X$, so it is *a* set of measures, but not measures on $X$.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry for changing my comment, but thanks for the prompt reply! What is $\beta X$ (can I still assume $X$ to be a metric space)?

Comment: [$\beta X$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification)

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks! Then shall the measures on $\beta X$ be restricted to $X$, (we can do this because $X$ is metric space and thus Tychonoff, the mapping from $X$ to its image in $\beta X$ is injective and homeomorphism), so Did can say the set of probability measures on $X$ is a subset of dual of $C_b$?

Comment: I'm not a person to say what Did can and what not. Anyway, he already said that, and that's true. Even more, $\mathcal M_1$ is a linear subspace of a continuous dual of $\mathrm b\mathfrak B_X$ - the Banach space of bounded measurable function for *any* measurable space $(X,\mathfrak B_X)$ endowed with a $\sup$-norm. To state that $\mathcal A$ is a subset of a continuous dual of $\mathcal B$ you only have to check that any element of $\mathcal A$ acts continuously on $\mathcal B$, the actual dual $\mathcal B^*$ does not have to be computed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer to the question, Martin's comment contains the key point. We have an isomorphism $C_b(X) \cong C(\beta X)$ where $\beta X$ is the [Stone-Čech compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) (defined for arbitrary topological spaces; some authors put extra conditions on $X$ but these are just the conditions required for the natural map $X \to \beta X$ to be an embedding), so by the ordinary Riesz representation theorem describes the dual of $C_b(X)$ in terms of measures on $\beta X$.

Comment: Thanks! But still not the same as what Did say. He said the probability measures on $X$ instead of $\beta X$ is a subset of dual of $C_b(X)$. For that purpoe, shall the measures on $βX$ be restricted to $X$ (we can do this because X is metric space and thus Tychonoff, the mapping from X to its image in βX is injective and homeomorphism)?

Comment: As Martin has already said, you don't need a representation theorem to see this. Just integrate measures on $X$ against functions in $C_b(X)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, could you clarify the following? I have a linear map $A: C_b(X,\mathbb R)$ to itself, where $X$ is complete, separable metric space, now can I talk about a map $B$ which is linear on the space of all  measures on $X$ and then can I define invariant measure of this map as $B\mu=\mu$? can I define an action of any probability measure or measure with any function from the $C_b(X, \mathbb R)$ like $<f, \mu>=\int f d\mu$